# Maximum frequency of my FPGA design in Quartus (Altera)

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I've been told that during compilation maximum frequency of the compiled design is estimated and can be viewed somewhere in logs - my problem is, I cannot find it. Any idea to where it's located in Quartus 13.0? Screenshot would be great, thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can view the maximum frequency (of your design) in the report of Time Quest Timing Analyzer:
[image: Altera Quartus]

Edit:
By the way you can check the maximum frequency in your log file as well, if you don't want to use the GUI. Check in your synthesis results the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer report: **unitname.sta.rpt**

Comment: I think I found it but it looks like im doing something wrong - http://i.imgur.com/wj6YMFF.png. Im assuming Im supposed to somehow tell Quartus, which line is my clock? Where can I do that?

Comment: Can you show me your critical warnings & warnings? Maybe they will give a hint why you don't get the timing result.

Comment: Doesn't this just show that the design can run at the Clock Speed specified by the designer (in the SDC file)? The design could run faster if you gave it a higher Clock Speed constraint because Quartus would continue to try to optimize it for the specified clock speed. So do you just have to keep increasing this Clock Speed constraint to find out the Absolute Maximum Frequency for my circuit?